# Xcode/Swift/Watchkit: Watch Extension unintentionally shows push notification on app launch?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, watchkit

I stumbled over the problem that everytime I launch my watch extension, a Push Notification pops up, which I never defined somewhere.

It looks like this:

[image]

I realized that the text on the buttons are defined in a apns-File in the Supporting Files directory of the watch extension as a JSON Object. 
However, when I push one of the buttons my app shows up. 
I really want to get rid of this Notification. Has anybody else had this problem before?

Thank you really much, your help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Somehow the scheme got tweaked in Xcode to have the watch interface set to "Dynamic Notification" not to main. You can change it here...

[image]